# Add child to custom QStandardItem

Tags: c++, qt

I have an object:

```
class Mando : public QObject, public QStandardItem {
      Q_OBJECT

   public:
      std::string getDescription() const;
      std::string getName() const;
      explicit Mando(boost::filesystem::path filen);

   private:
      boost::filesystem::path file;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Mando *)

Mando::Mando(boost::filesystem::path filen) {
   file= filen; }

std::string Mando::getName() const {
   return file.filename().string(); }

std::string Mando::getDescription() const {
   return std::string("XxxxX"); }
```

And model implementation:

```
ContentModel::ContentModel() : QStandardItemModel() {
   QStringList headers;
   headers << tr("Name") << tr("Description");
   setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers);
   setColumnCount(headers.count()); }

QVariant ContentModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
   if(role == Qt::DisplayRole)
      switch(index.column()) {
         case 0: return static_cast<Mando*>(item(index.row()))->getName().c_str();
         case 1: return static_cast<Mando*>(item(index.row()))->getDescription().c_str(); }
   return QStandardItemModel::data(index, role); }
```

I add objects like this:

```
model->appendRow(new Mando(boost::filesystem::path("/home/user/riri.ini")));
model->appendRow(new Mando(boost::filesystem::path("/home/user/fifi.ini")));
model->appendRow(new Mando(boost::filesystem::path("/home/user/loulou.ini")));
view= new QTreeView();
view.setModel(model);
```

All works fine, I get:

```
riri.ini              XxxxX
fifi.ini              XxxxX
loulou.ini            XxxxX
```

But,in some cases, I need to add one child.

```
riri.ini              XxxxX
  -> riri's child     YyyyY
fifi.ini              XxxxX
loulou.ini            XxxxX
  -> loulou's child   YyyyY
```

If I add a simple row in Mando instances, like this:

```
Mando::Mando(boost::filesystem::path filen) {
    file= filen;
    appendRow(new QStandardItem() /* or */ QList<QStandardItem*>); }
```

How to differentiate the father of the child in ContentModel::data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add child to an item, use `void QStandardItem::appendRow(QStandardItem * item)` on that item. The `QStandardItem` has also methods `child()` and `parent()` which will help you identify if there are parents/children. So does the `QModelIndex` class, so it also can help you identifying if there are children or parent related to the index.